# Android studio Framelayout - Listview under upper part

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently trying to replicate the user interface you can see on the picture down below. I have already created the upper part but I started struggling then I got to the listview part (The part below the blue background image). How can I make a listview stand under the upper part?

I have already tried to make a relativelayout but that wouldn't go to the bottom of the others after that I tried to put everything into a linearlayout that didn't work either

[image: The picture]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/upper_section"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="#144947">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:text="25"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
                android:background="#33e4e4e4">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/navn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/navn"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:text="Torsdag den 7. juni 2018"
                    android:textColor="@color/ColorSeconddaryText"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/upper_section"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="#144947">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:text="25"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/test_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
                android:background="#33e4e4e4">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/navn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/navn"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:text="Torsdag den 7. juni 2018"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/test_id"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**ORIGINAL**

Put your two RelativeLayouts inside a LinearLayout or another RelativeLayout.

FrameLayouts don't utilize positioning in their children (LinearLayouts naturally place one after another, RelativeLayouts allow more absolute positioning). When you have a FrameLayout with two children, they only way they would not be exactly on top of each other is one child has an excessive margin.

Comment: If I put the two Relativelayouts inside a linear my "upper section" gets destroyed.. (The overlay section is suddenly to different parts )

Comment: Did you try using another RelativeLayout and utilizing the `android:layout_below` tag?

Comment: Which layout did you specify in layout_below? The edit I posted worked in the Android Studio Resource Design view

Comment: Thank you. it worked. I must have made a mistake before.